# Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Usuarios' not found (1/1) Error Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Usuarios' not found

Tags: laravel, api, rest, lumen

tengo el siguiente método en el controlador

```
<?php
use App\Usuarios;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

class UsuariosController extends Controller
{

    public function index()
    {
        return Usuarios::all();
    }
}
```

y mi modelo es

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Usuario extends Model 
{


    protected $table = 'usuario';
    protected $primaryKey = 'idusuario';
    protected $fillable = [
        'nombre', 
        'nombreMascota',
        'correo',
        'celular',
        'direccion'
    ];


    protected $hidden = [
        'clave',
        'created_at',
        'updated_at'
    ];

}
```

mi ruta es la siguiente

```
$router->get('/usuarios', 'UsuariosController@index');
```

no entiendo porque me sale un error en el navegador si aparentemente todo esta bien ayuda por fa
entro con esta ur

Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Usuarios' not found
(1/1) Error
Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Usuarios' not found

in UsuariosController.php line 16
at UsuariosController->index()

Comment: la carpeta de mi api se llama proyecto de alli sigo el modelo base que tiene lumen

Comment: Tu pregunta va a terminar cerrada por que tienes un *typo* es decir te equivocaste en el namespace

Answer (score 1):

Tu modelo es Usuario en singular. 
Es decir estás importando App\Usuarios en tu controlador. Debes cambiarlo App\Usuario.

Éxitos